# How to identify the dyon being condensated at the ${\cal N}=2$ SUSY $u$-plane?

Tags: electromagnetism, field-theory, gauge-theory, supersymmetry, duality

For the $u$-plane monodromy at $u=u_0$

$$\mathcal{M}^{p,q}=\begin{pmatrix}
1+pq & p^2 \\
 -q^2 & 1-pq \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

the statement is that dyons with electric and magnetic charges $(p,q)$ become massless and condensate. My question is how to understand the dyon mass, which from the BPS mass formula shall be $M=|pa+qa_D|$ and is not clear to me how this becomes massless at $u=u_0$.